# What does this fuzzy court clerk stamp say? It's from a very old case in 1995 in the state of Washington

Tags: civil-law

[image: court clerk stamp]

At first I thought it says "MAILED" but that doesn't seem to work...or does it?  If you're familiar with court clerk stamps perhaps you can give advice as to what this is?  Thank you.

Comment: Better believe all records went that way Specially NA records

Comment: "Very old case in 1995"? I have active memories of 1995... For me "very old case" should be at least before WWII.

Comment: @user132647 I live in the UK so feel that "very old case" should be reserved for anything pre-1900. 1995 is basically yesterday!

Comment: Do you have a link to an online version of the document in question? Aside: 1995 is anything but "very old". The internet existed in 1995. There should be an online reference available if it is from 1995. I would call something from 1895 old (but not "very old"). Something from 1795 *might* be deemed "very old" from a US perspective, but not from a European perspective.

Answer (score 52):

**FILMED**

The document was archived onto microfilm.

User [@Dai](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/11316/dai) used the font Myriad Pro Bold to overlay this onto the image:

[image: Picture of the text "FILMED" overlayed onto the stamp's remains]

Comment: This appears to be dubious, at least to me.

Comment: @DavidHammen That the last letter is a "D" seems certain, and as far as I can tell the letter just left of center has to be an "L" as no other capital letter has 3 square corners but leaves the upper-right quadrant blank.  If the word really is "FILMED", then the "F" and the "I" seem odd, but I cannot come up with another word that would fit and make sense.

Comment: @RBarryYoung 3 solid corners on the firs tletter lend credability to it being "F", I can see the "L" and the "D", and the shape of the "M" is certainly probable

Comment: I don't see how it can be FILMED because the second-to-last letter doesn't look like it could possibly be an E.

Comment: Here's what I came up with after messing around in Photoshop for a few minutes - I don't know exactly what typeface that the court's rubber-stamps use, but _Myriad Pro Bold_ lines up very well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/stA1d.png

Comment: @Dai My only problem with your edit is you didn't give yourself enough credit!

Comment: If the font fits, you must upvote it.